# What is The "App" under "Products" in xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I made a "Truth or Dare" app and now I want to make a sister app of the same look and feel. Instead of starting from scratch and having to do all the cocoa pods stuff, I was hoping to just Copy and Paste my old project folder and edit as needed.

One thing I noticed is that the "app name" under "products" in the left-hand navigation toolbar refers to something I'm unfamiliar with.

Can someone help explain how I would best go about copy and pasting an app to start a new one? What would I need to replace?
[image: Screenshot]
Thank you

Comment: While copy and pasting will work in the short term, you now double your work in the future when you upgrade to new Swift versions, convert to SwiftUI for example or add new features. Instead, you should setup your project to have multiple targets, sharing common code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the ".App" extension file under the "Products" folder. It is recreated every time you run your app.
What you really need is to change:

> 1. "**Display Name**" of your app.
> 2. "**Bundle Identifier**" of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Though creating a target is the best option but you can rename your project and it will rename your target as well.

Click your project in the project navigator and then change the name under Identity and Type in file inspector. You will be asked to confirm rename project content items.